# How do you render a command button through ajax? It has to be dynamic

Tags: java, jsf

How do you render a command button through ajax so that its name changes from "start" to "stop" when clicked once and then again to "Start" when clicked a second time?

Comment: Only the value? Not only the name (value) of the button but also the task the button is assigned to needs to be changed from start to stop. User the `rendered` attribute the accomplish it.

Comment: @Tiny Good observation, but maybe the OP can change the action method behaviour depending on the button's current value.

Comment: I just want the name to change.. from start to stop and vice-versa... and without using amy jquery or javascripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a solution:

XHTML CODE

```
<h:commandButton action="#{yourBackingBean.onBtnClick}" value="#{yourBackingBean.buttonValue}" id="btn">
    <f:ajax execute="btn" render="btn" />
</h:commandButton>
```

MANAGEDBEAN CODE

```
public class YourBackingBean {

    private String buttonValue;

    public YourBackingBean() {

       buttonValue = "start";
    }

    public String onBtnClick() {

         buttonValue = buttonValue.equals("start") ? "stop" : "start";
         return null;
    }

    public String getButtonValue() {
         return buttonValue;
    }

    public void setButtonValue(String buttonValue) {
         this.buttonValue = buttonValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. It actually clears half of my doubts. But the code is not working. The name of the button is not changing'

Comment: @Learner edit your question posting the significant part of your XHTML and Java code, this way we can help you. For instance, did you declare your BackingBean in faces_context.xml or using annotation? or maybe you have to append your form id inside the execute and render attributes of <f:ajax />